# lerna on AzureDevops

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, yarnpkg, lerna

I am trying to make an azure Pipeline CI CD . 
I want have some dependencies in my project like Lerna .
so i tried to install it but i am getting an error that the command is not found when i try to build it

Thats my azure-pipelines.yml

```
# Node.js
# Build a general Node.js project with npm.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
  - release

pool:
  vmImage: "ubuntu-latest"

steps:
  - task: NodeTool@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: "10.0.0"
    displayName: "Install Node.js"

  - task: HelmInstaller@1
    inputs:
      helmVersionToInstall: 'latest'



  - script: |
      yarn global add lerna
      yarn global add @gov.au/pancake 
      yarn install
    displayName: "install lerna & pancake packages"


  - script: |
      yarn run build
    displayName: "NPM build"


  - script: |
      export NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=8192
    displayName: "set Env Variable "

  - script: |
      lerna run build --stream --concurrency=1 --include-dependencies
      lerna run docker-build-local --stream --concurrency=4 --include-filtered-dependencies
    displayName: "Build lerna "
```

and i am getting an error in the last script although lerna is installed

```
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/2d7931d0-403d-45a0-b7c9-9dfd7b5325f4.sh
/home/vsts/work/_temp/2d7931d0-403d-45a0-b7c9-9dfd7b5325f4.sh: line 1: lerna: command not found
/home/vsts/work/_temp/2d7931d0-403d-45a0-b7c9-9dfd7b5325f4.sh: line 2: lerna: command not found

##[error]Bash exited with code '127'.
```

Comment: You could add `system.debug=true` to get more detail log info for troubleshooting.  [Enable Verbose Debug Mode for TFS Build vNext](https://www.benday.com/2016/09/19/enable-verbose-debug-mode-for-tfs-build-vnext/)

Comment: Is lerna on devDependencies or dependencies?